# Django and two telegram bots

Tags: django, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I want to make 2 telegram bots with a common admin panel in Django.  The question is how best to implement this.  The first bot will be for sellers, let's call it “seller bot”.

The second one will be for "buyer bot" buyers.  I already have sketches for the first bot, a model in Django telegram_bot.  There should also be a chat so that you can communicate from the first to the second bot.  How can I best create a database to store users from two bots?  make one table and separate the data there by chat_id?

Then how can I determine which bot I am a member of?  I was thinking of creating two separate applications telegram_bot_seller and telegram_bot_buyer.

Please tell me which approach would be better.  I've never worked with two bolts at the same time

.. Each bot will have its own separate functions. But some, such as the technical support chat, are common (just don’t interfere with each other)

Comment: Hi welcome to [so]. This question is opinion based. Since you are new to the site, please kindly take a [tour] of the site. To ask better questions, see [ask].